# Showing spinner with custom tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, spinner

```
$('#widget .tabs li a').click(function (e) {
        $('#widget .tabs li').removeClass('ui-tabs-active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('ui-tabs-active');
        $('.group-tabContent').hide();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.group-tabContent').empty().load(url);
        $('.group-tabContent').show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

.. works great but I want to show a spinner while the page loads, where do I insert it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the top of your factory function, add something like this: 


`// Wait for window load

$(window).load(function() {

// Animate loader off screen

  $("ajax-loader-reference").animate({});

});`
where "ajax-loader-reference" is your class/id/element reference to the loader

Answer (score 0):

To do something while the new content loads, update the line `$('.group-tabContent').empty().load(url);` and include the complete function handler (see jQuery reference: http://api.jquery.com/load/ *If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed. The callback is fired once for each element in the jQuery collection, and this is set to each DOM element in turn.*):

```
// add show spinner code here
...

// make request for content
$('.group-tabContent').empty().load(url, function(response, status, xhr){

    // done loading content, now hide spinner
    ...

});
```